# Ionic app is very slow with angularJS filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm filtering trough about 200 entries. The JSONP file comes from my server.
The app is very slow and typing is on a android or iOS phone almost impossible.

I tried to limit with `track by item.storeName` but this doesn't help.

This is my html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Open">
    <ion-content class="bgstart">
      <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="">
      <h4 class="offline" ng-hide="online">Bitte verbinden Sie sich mit dem Internet</h4>
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchBox" class="search1" placeholder="Suchen...">

    <div ng-repeat="item in posts | filter:searchBox track by item.storeName" class="card" ng-show="searchBox">
      <h3 class="w shop">{{item.storeName}}</h3><br><br>
      <p class="w" ng-bind-html="item.openingHours[0]">{{item.openingHours[0]}}
      </p>
      <p class="w" ng-bind-html="item.openingHours[1]">{{item.openingHours[1]}}
      </p>
      <p class="w" ng-bind-html="item.openingHours[2]">{{item.openingHours[2]}}
      </p>
      <p class="w" ng-bind-html="item.openingHours[3]">{{item.openingHours[3]}}
      </p>
      <p class="w" ng-bind-html="item.openingHours[4]">{{item.openingHours[4]}}
      </p>
      <p class="w" ng-bind-html="item.openingHours[5]">{{item.openingHours[5]}}
      </p>
      <p class="w" ng-bind-html="item.openingHours[6]">{{item.openingHours[6]}}
      </p>
      <p class="c">
        <a href="tel:{{item.phone}}">
          <i ng-hide="item.noPhoneAndMap === 1 || item.noPhone === 1" class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </p>

      <p class="c">
        <a href="#" ng-click="GotoLink('{{item.addressLink}}')">
          <i ng-hide="item.noPhoneAndMap === 1 || item.noMap === 1" class="fa fa-map fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </p>
      <p class="c">
        <a href="#" ng-click="GotoLink('{{item.link}}')">
          <i ng-hide="item.noGlobe === 1" class="fa fa-globe fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </p>
      <img ng-hide="item.noPhoneAndMap === 1" ng-src="{{item.image}}" alt="" class="img-l" />
      <p class="w">
        {{item.customer}}
      </p>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

A JSON entry looks like this:

```
{
        "storeName": "",
        "addressLink": "",
        "phone": "",
        "image": "",
        "cumstomer": "",
        "description": "",
        "link": "",
        "openingHours": [
            ""
        ]
    }
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all of this stuff :

```
<p class="w" ng-bind-html="item.openingHours[0]">{{item.openingHours[0]}}
  </p>
```

to

2 things done there :

1. Remove useless {{}} displaying, you have already binded it in ng-bind-html. This may work but may create 2 watches for angular
2. Use of ng-repeat, more readable.

If your view don't need updating try to use ':' operator know as one time binding. It will bind data only once and won't watch for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **Crosswalk Webview** for performance issues.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Github [Repository](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)

Comment: Thank you, and what can I do with iOS?